# html change input tag to a button tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code for an audio recorder that uses input tags for the record and stop buttons:

```
<input type="button" class="start"  value="Record" />
<input type="button" class="stop" value="Stop" />
```

I'd like to change those input tags to < button > tags that execute the same functions, but I can't figure out how.  The code uses jquery, and I think the actual functions in the code are written to work with jquery.  Here's the part of the code that I think carries out the "start" and "stop" functions:

```
$('.recorder .start').on('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $recorder = $this.parent();

    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {
      var recorderObject = new MP3Recorder(audio_context, stream, { statusContainer:  $recorder.find('.status'), statusMethod: 'replace' });
      $recorder.data('recorderObject', recorderObject);

      recorderObject.start();
    }, function(e) { });
  });

  $('.recorder .stop').on('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $recorder = $this.parent();

    recorderObject = $recorder.data('recorderObject');
    recorderObject.stop();
```

The program has other .js files it uses, so perhaps more info about them is needed to answer this question.  I tried the following, but they didn't work:

```
<button onclick="start()">Record</button>
<button class="start">Record</button>
```

Comment: is your `<button class="start">Record</button>` inside `.recorder` element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a parent `.recorder` element like this :

```
<div class="recorder">
    <button class="start">Record</button>
    <button class="stop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be ok, if there are no other js, that is execude when you click the original buttons.

```
<button class="start">Record</button>
<button class="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and it didn't work.  Also, I mentioned that there are other .js files.  I looked through them and the only thing I found regarding a start and stop function didn't have any info within the function.  It was something along the lines of "function start(){  }" and no info inside of the function.